# Outputing logs to Console in Android

Tags: android, debugging

I'm using the command line to build a project that I am working on: I use it to generate an APK, transfer it to my device, and then run it in on my device.

I am trying to debug this application now, and I am not sure how to go about viewing the information that I have stored in my variables. If I insert a Log.i() statement, how would I go about viewing it either on my phone or on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your PC which is connected run in the cmd window:

adb logcat

this will update real time, if you wish to clear the logcat use

adb logcat -c

To filter by a TAG use:

adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"

These are what I find useful if you need more info let me know